# PL SQL - Procedure - table that holds a record of users who executed a procedure

Tags: stored-procedures, plsql, procedure, plsqldeveloper

Hi and apologies in advance if the question has already been asked. I haven't been able to come across the answer.

I'm wondering if there is a table that holds a record of oracle usernames that have executed a particular procedure or function.

I'm trying to create a procedure that can be called as a subprogram by another procedure. The procedure which i'm looking to create will create a log entry every time the other procedure is executed. Example below;

User_Name   = The Oracle user name of the person who executes the function.

Name   =  The name of the procedure or function.

LastCompileDT  =     The date/time the function or procedure was last compiled.

I'm a bit stuck on where to source the data from.
I've come across the all_source table but it only gives me the owner of the procedure and not the executing user.

Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: great answer has been given.  However, one thing to bear in mind is a normal stored proc will be rolledback together with the calling stored proc, which is normally not what you want for a stored proc used for auditing purpose.  You may want to make your auditing stored proc autonomous

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be a couple of ways to do that. Maybe someone else can suggest a method of extracting all this data from one data dictionary view. However, my method would be like this:

1. User_Name: use the keyword [USER](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:31051406979835). It returns the Oracle user that executed the procedure:

   ```
   SELECT USER FROM DUAL;
   ```

   However, if you are interested in the OS user who executed that procedure, then you can use the following

   ```
   SELECT sys_context( 'userenv', 'os_user' ) FROM DUAL;
   ```

   More on this [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:31051406979835). To my knowledge, this can be fetched on the fly only, and it is not logged anywhere by default. So you need to run it when you call the procedure.
2. Procedure Name: &
3. LastCompileDT : can be fetched from the view `USER_OBJECTS`

   ```
   SELECT OBJECT_NAME, LAST_DDL_TIME
   FROM USER_OBJECTS
   WHERE OBJECT_TYPE = 'PROCEDURE'
   AND OBJECT_NAME = '<YOUR PROCEDURE NAME>';
   ```

Comment: Thank you Hawk, this is exactly what i'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than rolling your own audit, you could use the inbuilt auditing table provided.

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm

```
--Create a test procedure as an example
CREATE PROCEDURE my_test_proc
AS
BEGIN
   NULL;
END my_test_proc;

--Turning on auditing executions of the proc
AUDIT EXECUTE ON my_test_proc BY ACCESS WHENEVER SUCCESSFUL;

--Run the proc
EXEC my_test_proc;

--check audit history
SELECT *
  FROM dba_common_audit_trail cat
 WHERE cat.object_name = 'MY_TEST_PROC';
```

The dba_common_audit_trail table has columns DB_USER, and OBJECT_NAME for your User_Name/Name.

For the last compiled time see Hawk's answer, or if you want to see a history of last DDL times you can add this to the audit

```
--Turn on auditing of creating procs
AUDIT CREATE PROCEDURE BY ACCESS;
```